# Bereft of or wanting in

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I would like to ask as to the difference between "bereft of" and " wanting in" in terms of meaning, formality and connotation they have.

For example:

> He was bereft of all hope.

can I say

He was wanting in all hope.

or

> He was wanting in confidence / common sense.

Can I say

He was bereft of confidence/common sense.

Answer (score 3):

To be **bereft** is to have had something (or someone) taken from you. You have been robbed of hope.

To be **wanting** is simply to lack something, to not have it. You lack hope. You have no hope.

You can have your confidence shaken and even taken from you.  But common sense is innate, so you either have it or you don't; it would be something you lacked.

Conceivably you could come up with a scenario where "bereft" would work, more or less, with common sense, for example:

> After taking LSD, they were bereft of common sense.

But it's something of a stretch. In the usual contexts, where someone's prudence and clear thinking is the subject, and you are speaking of their character under normal circumstances, common sense is either something you have or something you lack.

Comment: "Critics are also right in suggesting that his policy agenda is somewhat bereft of concrete plans."

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think that's not good writing, but words do accrete new meanings all the time, and if enough people start using *bereft* in that way, the original meaning will become blurred and faded.